# how to create a function question answer c#

Tags: c#

how to create a function that associates the name of the player who was chosen randomly thanks to the function I created and to the name of the question which is generated randomly with another function that I created.
Do you have to create a Player id and a question id.
I send you the code of the random functions. langage this variable liste contin player name

```
public static List<string> langage = new List<string>();

int index = Randomindex(langage.Count());

string Playername = langage.ElementAt(index)

public static int Randomindex(int mbplayers)
{
    var rand = new Random();
    int index = rand.Next();
    return index % mbplayers;
}

private List<Qes> qetquestion ()
{
    List<Qes> lesquestions = new List<Qes>();
    Qes qes1 = new Qes()
    {
        question = "Combien font 20 * 50",
        reponse = "1000"
    };
    Qes qes2 = new Qes()
    {
        question = "Quel est le prenom de bonarte",
        reponse = "Napoleon"
    };
    lesquestions.Add(qes1);
    lesquestions.Add(qes2);
    lesQuestions = lesquestions;
    return lesquestions;
}

public Qes getrandomQuestion()
{
    var random = new Random();
    var list = lesQuestions;
    int index = random.Next(list.Count);
    return list[index];
}
```

Comment: You'll need to share your current code and explain exactly where you are stuck trying to implement whatever you are implementing. This is much too vague for us to help. Read more [here on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you please share the code that you have written? And can you clarify what you mean by associating the name of the player to a function?

Comment: public static int Randomindex(int mbplayers)

        {
            var rand = new Random();
            int index = rand.Next();
            return index % mbplayers;
        }

Comment: The comments are not the place to share code that is needed to answer your question. Please edit your question according to the guidelines linked by @JNevill

Comment: So assuming these functions run, at this point you can do something like `question = getrandomQuestion();` and `player = Randomindex(mbplayers);` And you'll have a question and a player stored in a variable. What are you wanting to do with that?

Comment: @Peterswith i dont no

Comment: @Peterwith  public static List<string> langage = new List<string>(); 
the list that contains all the players  and the function to use which retrieves the name of the players in the list and displays the name in a label
''''''  int index = Randomindex(langage.Count());

                string Playername = langage.ElementAt(index);